# No me cargan imágenes en Servidor Apache con XAMPP

Tags: html, apache, xampp

He creado un proyecto en una carpeta "proyecto" dentro de htdocs "htdocs/proyecto/, hasta ahora me ha ido bien pero con php y html pero he creado una página html "gallety.html" para cargar unas imágenes "htdocs/proyecto/imgs/"

En "gallery.html" meto el siguiente código:

```
<img scr="imgs/1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Imagen1"/>
```

He probado combinaciones de la ruta como ponerlas directamente en `htdocs/proyecto/` y declararlas sin ruta

```
<img scr="1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Imagen1"/>
```

también con variantes como `"./imgs/1.jpg"`, hasta incluso metiendo

```
<img scr="http://localhost/proyecto/imgs/1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Imagen1" />
```

si meto `http://localhost/proyecto/imgs/1.jpg` directamente en la barra de navegación me muestra la imagen pero si la meto en el html sólo muestra el alt, 
en fin, que no soy capaz de que mueste la imagen. He probado por si acaso con otros navegadores y tampoco funciona si la cargo desde html pero si accedo 
directamente a la ruta localhost si que me las muestra.

La versión de XAMPP que uso es la última xampp_7.3.7 que viene con Apache 2.4.39, MariaDB 10.3.16, PHP 7.3.7

Comment: La raíz de tu servidor web es *htdocs* por lo que poniendo `src="/proyecto/imgs/nombreImagen.extensionImagen"` debería valerte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fijate bien que estás escribiendo "scr" en vez de "src".

Quedaría:

```
<img src="imgs/1.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Imagen1">
```

Comment: Gracias, era eso, me he vuelto loco, lo peor es que el editor no me marca el error de sintaxis, ni VSCodium ni eclipse.

Comment: De nada hombre, errores pequeños de estos son los que mas tiempo hacen perder :D, buscas la gran cosa y al final es un punto y coma o alguna letra, todos pasamos por ello.  Si es todo, marca el tema como cerrado dandole al "tick" de la respuesta. Saludos :DD